# Current State of NTLK via Jython

Tags: jython, nltk

Can someone please clarify.

Is it currently possible to compile NTLK source using Jython (seems was not possible a few years ago so I am wondering if things have changed).

If anyone did manage to do that, can you please provide some guidance.
If not possible, what is the best (most elegang) approach to use NTLK from within Java (and I prefer not to launch a process each time).

Thank you very much in advance.

Edward

Comment: [Pyro](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/) is a good way to connect CPython and Jython processes.